# Complex filter between 2 objects and a boolean

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I have this array `burgerActions` :

```
[
  {
    statusId: 2,
    label: 'Accept'
  },
  {
    statusId: 3,
    label: 'Reject'
  },
  {
    label: 'Consult'
  },
  {
    label: 'Transfer'
  }
]
```

and this object `status` which can be either :

```
{
  "label": "Accept",
  "id": 2
}
```

or :

```
{
  "label": "Reject",
  "id": 3
}
```

In a first case you have to create a new array from `burgerActions` array where the `statusId` is not equivalent to the id of the `status` object that we have (we can only have one `status` object of the 2 cases that I listed).
For that I used the `filter` method :

```
const result =  burgerActions.filter((element) => {
  return element.statusId !== recommendation.status.id
})
```

In the second case I need a complex conditioning adding with boolean

```
const statusRef = recommendation.recipient
```

In a first case I want if `statusRef` is `false` filter the last object in the `burgerAction` (`{label: 'Transfer'}`) but not in the case if `statusRef` is true.
I need a method that does this type of filter without using the `if ()` conditions because there are several cases to handle.

Comment: give a correct input and output?

Comment: please add the wanted results as well.

Comment: What do you mean by *filter 2 objects and **in addition a boolean***?

Comment: I edited the post

Comment: @MouadEnnaciri I posted an answer, please check it and tell me if that's what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to filter the objects that doesn't have the same `statusId` as in the `recommendation.status.id` and if `recommendation.recipient === true` filter the ones that doesn't have `statusId`, you can use this condition in the filter callback function:

```
element.statusId !== recommendation.status.id && recommendation.recipient ? element.statusId != null : true;
```

Where `&& recommendation.recipient ? element.statusId != null : true` means that if `recommendation.recipient` is `true` filter elements with a `statusId`.

Here's how should be your code:

```
var recommendation = {
  status: {
    "label": "Pending",
    "id": 1
  },
  recipient: true
};

const result = burgerActions.filter((element) => {
  return element.statusId !== recommendation.status.id && recommendation.recipient ? element.statusId != null : true;
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
var burgerActions = [{
    statusId: 2,
    label: 'Accept'
  },
  {
    statusId: 3,
    label: 'Reject'
  },
  {
    label: 'Consult'
  },
  {
    statusId: 1,
    label: 'Transfer'
  }
];

var recommendation = {
  status: {
    "label": "Pending",
    "id": 1
  },
  recipient: true
};

const result = burgerActions.filter((element) => {
  return element.statusId !== recommendation.status.id && recommendation.recipient ? element.statusId != null : true;
});


console.log(result);
```